# readline(): can R understand if one is typing from Rstudio or from command-line?

Tags: r, cmd, rstudio, readline

I have a portion of code that "sounds" like:

```
bla bla () <- bla R stuff bla
...
p <- readline()
cat("This is the amazing parameter ",p)
```

It obvioulsy works on the command line. The problem is that Rstudio have issues about with the interactivity.

So, there exists a way in which R understand if you're typing from a command line or from Rstudio. Something like:

```
bla bla () <- bla R stuff bla
...
if(RstudioInput() == true){
    p <- "param"
} else {
   p <- readline()
}
cat("Again, this is the awesome parameter ",p)
```

Summarizing, I need to know both if the code is running from Rstudio and also if the code is running from the command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `Sys.getenv("RSTUDIO")` it returns `"1"` when running RStudio and `""` when not running RStudio.